# What did Stack Exchange use to build & do the data shaping for the Stack Exchange API V2.2?

Tags: discussion

I know that Stack Exchange is a Microsoft shop. I know you are using Asp.Net MVC 5 and SQL Server 2014 CTP2 from this [Which tools and technologies are used to build the Stack Exchange Network?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-are-used-to-build-the-stack-exchange-network).

However, the API you expose does some interesting things. You can shape your data, get a guid back and then use that guid to query the data and get the same result set back. Is Stack Overflow using OData and perhaps typeless models to shape the data on the backend or are you doing something else?

Comment: Magic mostly, magic and unicorn dust

Comment: Answered by an SE staff member, so it must be authoritative.

Comment: I'm more (or equally) impressed with the documentation, particularly as it looks at least partially generated automatically (or automagically perhaps).

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett [Maybe that's why it's so darn unhelpful.](http://stackapps.com/q/4577/21692)